# How to shift a pcolor plot along the x axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, x-axis

I'd like to shift a pcolor plot along the x direction. But I'm not sure how to do it, as it's not as simple as using **plot** with a vector that specifies the x values

With this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)
Z = np.random.rand(6, 5)

tk = list(range(0,10+1))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7.2, 2.3))

ax.pcolor(Z)
ax.set_xticks(tk)

plt.show()
```

It produced this plot:

[image]

However I want the heatmap shifted to the right to start at x = 2, for example, like the following plot:

[image]

What am I missing???

As a side question, if I swap lines 11 and 12 to:

```
ax.set_xticks(tk)
ax.pcolor(Z)
```

I get this plot with the x axis contracted to the range [0,5]. I'm not sure why setting ticks before adding pcolor would do that?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One 'simple' way of achieving that is by just adding 2 empty (NaN) values to the Z:

```
Z = np.insert(Z, 0, np.nan, axis=1)
Z = np.insert(Z, 0, np.nan, axis=1)
```

Gives:
[image]

Comment: Thanks. That seems to have done the trick and is good for now. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

`pcolor` takes optional `x` and `y` arguments, which can be used to set the axes.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.close("all")

rng = np.random.default_rng()
Z = rng.random((6,5))

x0 = 2
y0 = 0
x = np.arange(x0, x0+Z.shape[1])
y = np.arange(y0, y0+Z.shape[0])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.pcolor(x, y, Z)
ax.set_aspect(1)
fig.tight_layout()
fig.show()
```

Alternatively, you can you [`pcolormesh`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pcolormesh.html#differences-pcolor-pcolormesh), which the matplotlib documentation says is typically preferred. In this case, it is a drop-in replacement.